# mysql table crashes only when replica server running

Tags: mysql, database-replication, myisam

I have a table that crashes often, but only seems to crash when the replica is running.

The table is MyISAM.  The table has 2 mediumtext fields.  The error I get when making a delete statement is this: "General error: 1194 Table 'outlook_emails' is marked as crashed and should be repaired".

I wonder if this has to do with the binary log.  However, it doesn't seem to happen when the binary log is running but the replica is down.

Any idea what is happening or what I can do to solve it or investigate further?

Comment: Change to InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames can you put that as an answer and explain why and i'll mark it as the accept answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Table '...' is marked as crashed and should be repaired".

That error occurs (usually) when the MySQL server as been rudely restarted, *and* the table is ENGINE=MyISAM.

The temporary fix is to run `CHECK TABLE`, which will then suggest that you run `REPAIR TABLE`.  The tool `myisamchk` is a convenient way to do them, especially since there could be several tables so marked.

The Engine InnoDB has radically different internals.  It avoids the specific issue that MyISAM has, and does a much more thorough job of recovering from crashes.

Switching to InnoDB requires `ALTERing` your tables.  Here is more discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb